# Calabash-Android Run/Resign Gives Error

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

I am trying to set up Calabash-android to run with a test app but keep getting the following error. I am not sure if its a problem with the way I set it up or not. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/calabash-android/dependencies.rb:220:in `basename': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/calabash-android/dependencies.rb:220:in`platform_directory'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/calabash-android/dependencies.rb:247:in `locate_android_dependencies'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/calabash-android/dependencies.rb:125:in`setup'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:104:in`build_test_server_if_needed'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/bin/calabash-android-run.rb:16:in `calabash_run'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/bin/calabash-android:84:in`'
>       from /usr/local/bin/calabash-android:23:in `load'
>       from /usr/local/bin/calabash-android:23:in`'

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the ANDROID_HOME environment variable setup.  If you have done this already then there may be an issue with how you have it configured.

The bit of the calabash code that this error has come uses the sdk directory - https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/dependencies.rb#L214